# Group like JSON objects into arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model returned by a library in the following format:

```
var givenData = [{"fName": "john"}, {"fName": "mike"}, {"country": "USA"}]
```

How do I group the "`fName`" together and add '`[]`' to get:

```
{ 'fName[]': ['john','mike'],'country[]': ['USA'] };
```

**Note `country` and `fName` are not related at all.

Comment: you... loop over the array, and on each iteration, modify the output object based on the current array item...

Comment: Hmm.. why is this getting downvoted

Comment: probably because it's a work request rather than a problem.

Comment: It's getting downvoted because SO is not a code-writing service; please review [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just curious, why the answers are downvoted then ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious for the future, I couldn't figure out how to group, and tried serializers. Should I have put that into the question?

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak maybe, someone thought they weren't useful. it is in fact possible for something to be both correct and not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion (using ES6 syntax)

```
const transformData = (data) => {
  const newData = {}
  data.forEach( (item) => {
    for (let key in item) {
       const newKey = key + "[]"
       if (!newData.hasOwnProperty(newKey)) newData[newKey] = []
       newData[newKey].push(item[key])
    }
  })
  return newData
}

/* added some extra keys just to test */
let givenData = [
  {"fName": "john", "country": "England"}, 
  {"fName": "mike"}, 
  {"country": "USA"},
  {"language": "English"}
]

console.log(transformData(givenData))
/*
{
    "fName[]": ["john","mike"],
    "country[]": ["England","USA"],
    "language[]":["English"]
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the array and push the date to the desired field.

```js
var givenData = [{"fName": "john"}, {"fName": "mike"}, {"country": "USA"}]

var result = {
  'fName[]': [],
  'country[]': []
};

givenData.forEach(function (data) {
  if (data.fName) {
    result['fName[]'].push(data.fName);
  }
  
  if (data.country) {
    result['country[]'].push(data.country);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the key and build an object with the key and arrays as properties.

```js
var givenData = [{"fName": "john"}, {"fName": "mike"}, {"country": "USA"}],
    grouped = givenData.reduce(function (r, o) {
        var key = Object.keys(o)[0] + '[]';
        r[key] = r[key] || [];
        r[key].push(o[Object.keys(o)[0]]);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, should leave a comment for the reason

Comment: Agreed, these are all good answers, someone downvoted all of them

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

`` const newData = givenData.reduce(function (r, o) {
   const key = `${Object.keys(o)[0]}[]`;
   return { ...r, [key]: [ ...r[key], o[key] ] }
 }, {}); ``

This doesn't modify your original data and is very clean.